# Tabular Model SSAS (visual studio)

Tags: ssas, ssas-tabular

Hi I am trying to create a Tabular Model in Visual Studio, but I keep getting the following error :   "An error occurred while connecting to the server".

I tried with all compatibility levels and I keep getting the same error so I know that's not the issue, also when I tested the connection to the server it was successful.
Any clue of why I am getting this issue?
Thank you.
[image]

Comment: Do you have the appropriate permissions on the Analysis Server?

Comment: @TJ_ Yes I am admin.

Comment: Can you connect to the Analysis Server via SQL Management Studio?

Comment: @TJ_ Yes I can, I don't have any issue logging, I am also a server admin.

Comment: @Rachel can you just use the integrated workspace? Do you have enough RAM on your laptop to support model development locally?

Comment: @GregGalloway the integrated workspace means I won't have the cube on the company server, and I will be using that cube for reports so I need it available 24/7

Comment: @Rachel you misunderstand. The workspace is just personal for development. It will have a GUID in the database name. When you are done you deploy to the server.

Comment: @gregGalloway  ah I'll try that then, Thank you!

Comment: @GregGalloway  still same problem,  when I deploy it to the server gives me same error message " An error occurred while connecting to the server".

Comment: Can you open SQL Server Profiler and connect it to SSAS on the server? See if it shows other errors during deployment.